# Set Multi Tenant in Active Admin Controllers (required for Searchkick index)

Tags: activeadmin, searchkick, acts-as-tenant

I am using Active Admin in my multi tenant app.  I also use Searchkick which has a custom tenant specific index in each model:

```
class Budget < ApplicationRecord

  multi_tenant :company

  searchkick inheritance: true,index_name: -> { [MultiTenant.current_tenant.tenant_name, model_name.plural, Rails.env].join('_') }

end
```

The issue is that in AA this logic fails because on the tenant is set.  I want to be able to set this in AA when updating a record.

For example I would update http://localhost:4000/admin/budgets/dt2kqvgm where `dt2kqvgm` is the Friendly ID of the record.  So I want to call something like:

```
MultiTenant.current_tenant = Budget.friendly.find(params['budget']['company_id'])
```

when I create / update a record etc.

Currently I get:

```
undefined method `tenant_name' for nil:NilClass
```

because in my application controller the tenant is set based on the user authentication to scope the current company etc.  In AA I want/ need to set this based on the params which it seems you can't access from the AA controller logic.  My params look like this in AA:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"PrhNGnPvV1Qfb5RCwTVv4Wwz9tjf9SFy2VWDcyJXoFLytM8y5ZAyF7h8I7xa+fy01E9Fc/v2CvR52I4/LKOLHQ==", "budget"=>{"company_id"=>"9", "name"=>"qweqwe", "description"=>"qweqwe", "notes"=>"qwee", "flag_active"=>"1", "slug"=>"dt2kqvgm", "title"=>"qweqwe"}, "commit"=>"Update Budget", "controller"=>"admin/budgets", "action"=>"update", "id"=>"dt2kqvgm"}
```

Comment: Should be `permitted_params`?

Comment: When this breaks and I roll back up in code it seems the params are not even available in the AA controller.

Comment: `permitted_params` should be available. I recommend adding a `pry` breakpoint and poking around.  You can see `permitted_params` being read [here](https://github.com/activeadmin/inherited_resources/blob/e51a54d0d5c8c701ef77ea97a74de9c19d637a50/lib/inherited_resources/base_helpers.rb#L354)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best way to do this but it works.  I am know it needs tweaks but it's a start - you needs to:

1. set an `around_action` filter
2. add permitted_params

> ```
> around_action :set_tenant, only: :update
>
> controller do
>
>   def set_tenant
>     MultiTenant.with(Company.find(resource.company_id)) do
>       yield
>     end
>   end
>
>   def permitted_params
>     params.permit location: %[ company_id ]
>   end
>
> end
> ```

It would seem this is required for each controller.  Perhaps there is a way to add this as a default AA filter?

I also added the filter to just the `update` action.